# Indentation Error: expected an indented block (Nltk cook book)

Tags: python, indentation, spyder

I'm following Cook Book and i have come across with this error.In line 15 there is some problem and i'm not able to solve this.

**Code**:

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
]
class RegexpReplacer(object):
def__init__(self,patterns=replacement_patterns):self.patterns=[(re.compile(regex),repl)for(regex,repl)inpatterns]
def replace(self, text):
s = text
for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
return s
```

**Error**:
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: actually i'm following a book and that's how it's written in it.

Comment: That is very unlikely. The most important character in Python is the space, you left out many important spaces.

Comment: really? Well the book is totally wrong if it's written without any indentation like that. Google "python indentation" for a number of easily understandable guides as to what Python expects in terms of indentation. (Although it's really just common sense, as it's how you *should* indent your code in any language. Python just makes it a syntax requirement, rather than just a matter of good style.)